# Automatically zip some files in a folder

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a program to automatically ZIP some files in a folder every x minutes. 
Is there a program to do it? Or is there an option to do this in the softwares like WinRar or 7-zip?

Thanks...

Comment: I really don't know what the use case here is, but if you want the files to use less space, you can just mark the folder as compressed on the NTFS folder properties on Windows, and it uses a low-compression algorithm that can help you

Comment: If you really need to only zip some (not all) files in a folder, you should look into creating a script which runs e.g. 7-zip on just those file. [Python](https://www.python.org) would likely be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command line in **7zip** to enable you to run it automatically.

On a command line, type the following to bring up the help:

```
7z /?
```

Here's a page that describes a bit the command line options:
[Command Line Version User's Guide](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/index.htm)

Once you got that command working, you can create a recurring job in the **windows task scheduler**, and have it execute every X number of minutes.